# EntityUtils reports NoApplicableCode exception for Android request

Tags: android, json, exception, httpclient, http-post

I am trying to retrieve a JSON file from a web service using the following [URL](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien%3aBAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&bbox=16.377681,48.211448,16.379829,48.21341,EPSG:4326&maxfeatures=10). That works fine when I use a browser to send the HTTP request.
For the Android application I came up with the following code.

```
// Android request
String url = "http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geoserver/ows?service=WFS" +
             "&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BAUMOGD" +
             "&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json" +
             "&bbox=16.377681,48.211448,16.379829,48.21341,EPSG:4326" +
             "&maxfeatures=10"
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Though, `EntityUtils` does not output a JSON file but this XML exception.

```
// Value of result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
input contained no data</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I hope you can see what wents wrong ...

Comment: @zapl Perfect! That works. Do not ask me why but this buggy code worked on March 26th. They must have changed the server somehow. How can I grand you the **answer** now?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTML specifications technically define the difference between "GET" and "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded (by a browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is to appear within a message body. > [[source](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)]

Since you do encode the full request into the URL (`request=GetFeature` etc.) => use `HttpGet` instead.

Might even work imo with post since the url should still be transmitted to the server but the server would need to detect that the post request is actually a get request and behave accordingly.